# Installing Anbox using apt requires deleting busybox.Why?

Tags: debian, software-installation, busybox

While installing a package ,as always you receive a list of to be installed,to be uninstalled,downgraded,upgraded , etc.
The same is for Anbox .My problem is why installation of Anbox require uninstalling busybox?

Its also note worthy that Anbox itself says:

> To install Anbox your system need to support snaps. We do not
> officially support any other distribution method of Anbox at the
> moment but there are community made packages for various distributions
> (e.g. Arch Linux).

---

Here are some links related to mentioned packages:

[BusyBox_Debian_Buster_10_Stable](https://packages.debian.org/buster/busybox)

[Anbox_Debian_Buster_10_Stable_Contrib](https://packages.debian.org/buster/anbox)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `anbox` package depends on `lxc`, which recommends `lxc-templates`, which recommends `busybox-static`, which conflicts with `busybox`. Thus installing `anbox` ends up replacing `busybox` with `busybox-static`, by default. Note that you won’t lose any functionality because of this.

If you want to keep `busybox`, install `anbox` without recommended packages:

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends anbox
```

`aptitude` can answer such questions for you:

```
$ aptitude why-not anbox busybox
p   anbox          Depends    lxc (>= 1:3.0.0)
p   lxc            Recommends lxc-templates (>= 3.0.2-1)
p   lxc-templates  Recommends busybox-static
p   busybox-static Conflicts  busybox
```